# Trying to convert a bunch of C++ codes into Java - if statement

Tags: java, c++, opencv, operators, javacv

i was trying to write some C++ codes into java, now i have writter following code into java but it is throwing errors!

```
if(ShapeNotFound && xd*yd - nPixel[k] < xd+yd)              // Condition for RECTANGLE
{

    System.out.print("\n      "+in+"  \t     Rectangle \n");
    fileWriter3.write("\n      "+in+"  \t     Rectangle \n");
    Shape[k] = 2;
    ShapeNotFound = 0;

}
```

I am getting following error :

> ```
> The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean
> ```

Please help, tell me how to write the above if condition correctly in java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C and C++ both assume that for integers 0 is false and all other values are true.

Java does not make the same assumption so you need to add a check for int!=0 into the expression i.e.:

```
if((ShapeNotFound!=0) && (xd*yd - nPixel[k] < xd+yd))
```

Or alternatively your ShapeNotFound variable should be of type boolean not int.

It would be worth converting variable names etc to Java style guidelines as well.

Answer (score 0):

Java can not convert `int` into `boolean` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ShapeNotFound` is an integer, but you're implicitly treating it like a boolean (true or false). Java only likes genuinely boolean expressions, so you'll need to change the condition to something like this:

```
if (ShapeNotFound != 0 && xd*yd - nPixel[k] < xd+yd)
```

For readability, I'd suggest putting some brackets round each part of the condition. That's an issue of personal preference though.